# Marginalise over n dimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I am trying to figure out how to handle multidimensional arrays in julia. I have a multidimensional array `A = rand(5,5,5)`.

I am trying to figure out how to get `A[1,1,:]` or `A[1,:,1]` or `A[:,1,1]` with the position of the `:` given by an input m.

I have come up with

```
indexData = [:,1,2]
indexData[1],indexData[m] = indexData[m],indexData[1]
data = A[indexData[1],indexData[2],indexData[3]]
```

but this seems overly complicated and would not scale if the dimension of `A` was unknown. Is there some better ways of solving this?

Comment: The Marginalise in the title suggest summing over some dimension (as in a marginal probability). If the idea is to just select elements, perhaps the title is confusing.

Comment: Yes, in the end I will marginalise over the specified dimensions. I am however dealing with logpdf so cannot directly sum over the pdf. If you have a better idea for the title I will gladly change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following might fit the bill:

```
getshaft(A,ii,m) = [A[(i==m?j:ii[i] for i=1:length(ii))...] for j=1:size(A,m)]
```

Consider the following example:

```
julia> A = reshape(collect(1:27),3,3,3)
3×3×3 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9

[:, :, 2] =
 10  13  16
 11  14  17
 12  15  18

[:, :, 3] =
 19  22  25
 20  23  26
 21  24  27

julia> getshaft(A,(1,2,3),1)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 22
 23
 24
```

The second parameter is an element index, and the third chooses a dimension. `getshaft` will return the vector of values including the element selected by the second parameter along the dimension specified by the third parameter. The first parameter is, of course, the array.

--- Update ---

A quick review, suggested an even faster and cleaner implementation of the same function:

```
getshaft(A,ii,m) = A[(i==m?Colon():ii[i] for i=1:length(ii))...]
```

Using slice indexing might benefit from faster index calculations or other AbstractArray sorcery in the background.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I need !

Comment: Thanks, here is what I have used in the end if anyone is interested. `getshaft(A,ii,m) = A[(i in m?Colon():shift!(ii) for i=1:(length(ii)+length(m)))...]`.